# advice needed on JPanel - Drawing Area & listeners

Tags: java, jframe, paint

below is the code i currently have for the drawing class, iv been looking for documents which teach me how to create 3 shapes on screen.

i have a jframe, with menus to select the shape (seen below) ect.

```
if (clickedMenu.getText().equals("Square")){                    
value = pane.returnslider();
shape = new ASquare(value);
```

so my question is: how to i edit the below class to create a 2D square that appears on my Jframe which changes size depending on the slider value?

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package assignment;

import java.awt.Graphics;

/**
 *
 * @author Steven
 */
public class MyDrawing extends javax.swing.JPanel {

/**
 * Creates new form MyDrawing
 */
 @Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
     super.paintComponent(g);    // paints background


  }   
}
```

---

some code from my jpanel that would maybe help you in answering my question:

```
public class MyChangeAction implements ChangeListener {

    //complete code here
    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent ce) {
        double value = slider.getValue();
        String str = Double.toString(value);
        sliderLabel.setText(str);
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.0");

        boundary_length.setText("" +     df.format(MyFrame.shape.computeBoundaryLength(value)));
        area.setText("" + df.format(MyFrame.shape.computeArea(value)));
    }
} // end class

public double returnslider() {
    return slider.getValue();
}
```

---

my square class:

```
package assignment;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

/**
 *
 * @author b00560806
 */
public class ASquare extends MyShape {

double value;

public ASquare(double value) {
    this.value = value;
}


@Override
public double computeBoundaryLength(double Length) 
{
    thelength=(4*Length);
    return thelength;
}

@Override
public double computeArea(double Length) 
{
    thearea=(Length*Length);
    return thearea;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override 
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);    // paints background

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.setStroke(new Stroke((int)returnslider));
    // rest of drawing.
}
```